# Using math to change positions of objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I’ve got a big request. It involves quite a bit of math, which was never my strong suit, so I thought, I’d ask the guys on Stackoverflow to help me out.

I’m working on this solar system interactive animation using Javascript. I’m using trigonometric functions to create full 360 degrees circled rotations around objects, for planets around the sun. I know, planets rotate elliptically, but I didn’t want it to make it too hard on myself.

```
function rotate_point(originX, originY, body) {
    body.angle +=  (1.0 / body.period); //calculates the angle, divided by distance from center of body
    var ang = body.angle * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; //calculates full 360° rotation required based on angle
    var r = body.orbit;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + originX, 
        y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + originY 
    };} // generic rendering of a unit orbital progression of a planet
```

As you can see that part is all done though, my question:

What I would I need to “tweak” in order for the effect that sort of drives the objects toward the center of the sun. Like if I were to suddenly make the gravitational pull that much stronger that it would pull on the orbit of the planets so you see them crashing eventually toward that center.

Is it doable with any change to the above code, and if so, what would that code need to look like?

I’ve got a JS fiddle for what I’ve got, I hope there’s some smart guys that see the challenge in this and help me out!

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qk3qrwbp/)

Comment: I appreciate your motivation in trying to tackle this, however, StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service. A quick Google search returned a huge amount of information on this subject--even complete jQuery libraries which embed gravitational effects The solution is out there. Search for "js function for gravitational pull." The top 5 results are great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to update your code to use Kepler's third law of planetary motion. Since you're using circular orbits where mass(planet) << mass(sun), Kepler's third law basically is just a statement of conservation of angular momentum.

Rotational momentum is defined as the product of the system's moment of inertia (*I*) and angular velocity (*omega*) as measured in *rad/s*.

Mathematically, this is just:

> *I1* * *omega1* = *I2* * *omega2*

Expressing this in terms of quantities we can use:

> I = m * r^2 
>   omega = r * dTheta/dt

So by the property conservation:

> I1 * omega1 = I2 * omega2

Mass cancels out on both sides leaving us with an expression for *r* and *omega*.

> r1^2 * omega1 = r2^2 * omega2

So given a change in radius, we can calculate the necessary change in angular velocity. If *r1* and *omega1* are the initial radius and rotational velocity, then the new rotational velocity for a given orbit radius is expressed by:

> omega2 = omega1 * (r1/r2)^2

This can be accomplished with the addition of a single line of code to the `rotate_point` function to update the velocity:

```
function rotate_point(originX, originY, body) {
    velocity_gain = Math.pow(sol["Earth"].orbit/body.orbit, 2)
    body.angle += velocity_gain * (1.0 / body.period); //calculates the angle, divided by distance from center of body
    var ang = body.angle * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; //calculates full 360° rotation required based on angle
    var r = body.orbit * orbitScale
    return {
       x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + originX, 
       y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + originY 
    };
  }
    // generic rendering of a unit orbital progression of a planet

  function planetrotation ( planet ) {
      var x, y, x_sun, y_sun, e, c_new;
      e = document.getElementById ( planet );
      x_sun = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( "Sun" ).getAttribute ( "cx" ) );
      y_sun = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( "Sun" ).getAttribute ( "cy" ) );
      c_new = rotate_point ( x_sun, y_sun, sol[planet], 0.5 );
      e.setAttribute ( "cx", c_new.x );
      e.setAttribute ( "cy", c_new.y );
    } // Rotations of the planets around Sun    

  var sol = { 
    Mars:   { period: 5.2, orbit: 400, angle: 51.0},
    Earth:  { period: 5.2, orbit: 300, angle: 51.0},
    Venus:  { period: 5.2, orbit: 200, angle: 51.0}
    };

  function animate () {
    planetrotation("Venus");
    planetrotation("Earth");
    planetrotation("Mars");
  }
```

Here's the Fiddle simulating 3 planets: https://jsfiddle.net/8kcj3bvz/

[image]

Basically, this equality is saying that as the orbital radius decreases, angular velocity must increase for momentum (and energy in this case) to be conserved.

Long term you might want to consider using Euler's method to simulate this system. It's actually quite simple for gravitational bodies like this and can be quite powerful when simulating more than two bodies.

**EDIT**

Just a side note that the orbital velocity is only a function of its radius provided the satellite is much less massive than the parent body. So it's actually redundant to define `period` and `angle` in your code.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your clear explanation. Even though I got an answer to the question from someone else that's not as difficult to adjust, I will look into implementing your suggestion too.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reduce the radius of the orbit:

```
body.orbit = Math.max(body.orbit-.25, 0);
```

```js
function rotate_point(originX, originY, body) {
  body.angle += (1.0 / body.period); //calculates the angle, divided by distance from center of body
  var ang = body.angle * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; //calculates full 360° rotation required based on angle
  body.orbit = Math.max(body.orbit - .25, 0);
  var r = body.orbit;
  return {
    x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + originX,
    y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + originY
  };
}
// generic rendering of a unit orbital progression of a planet

function planetrotation(planet) {
  var x, y, x_sun, y_sun, e, c_new;
  e = document.getElementById(planet);
  x_sun = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Sun").getAttribute("cx"));
  y_sun = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Sun").getAttribute("cy"));
  c_new = rotate_point(x_sun, y_sun, sol[planet]);
  e.setAttribute("cx", c_new.x);
  e.setAttribute("cy", c_new.y);
} // Rotations of the planets around Sun    

var sol = {
  Earth: {
    period: 5.2,
    orbit: 200,
    angle: 51.0
  }
};

function animate() {
  planetrotation("Earth");
}

var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #FFFF00;
}
.st1 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="solarsystem">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="solly" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
    <g id="Sun2">
      <circle id="Sun" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="30" />
      <circle id="Earth" class="st1" cx="375.4" cy="289.7" r="10.5" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Of course physically it wouldn't behave exactly like this.

Comment: I would never have guessed the answer to be able to be written down in a single line of code. I feel silly, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To make is simple you can linearly change the radius during time. For example:

```
function rotate_point(originX, originY, body) {
    body.angle +=  (1.0 / body.period); //calculates the angle, divided by distance from center of body
    body.orbit -= body.period*.04;
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```